# Android MediaPlayer doesn’t work after a while

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

In Android, `MediaPlayer` doesn’t work after a while. The code is below:

Playing music:

```
sayib1 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.sayib1);
sayib2 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.sayib2);
sayib3 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.sayib3);
sayib4 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.sayib4);
sayib5 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.sayib5);
sayib6 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.sayib6);
sayib7 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.sayib7);
sayib8 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.sayib8);
sayib9 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.sayib9);

mpsayi = new MediaPlayer();

final String sourcestr = "android.resource://" + this.getPackageName();

sayib1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener () {
    public void onClick (View sayiv1){

        mpsayi.reset();

        mpsayi.seekTo(0);

        sayilayoutt1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        sayilayoutt2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        sayibutonlar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        sayiimagev.setImageResource(R.drawable.sayi1);
        sayiimagev.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        new Handler().postDelayed( new Runnable() {

            public void run(){

                sayilayoutt1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                sayilayoutt2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                sayibutonlar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                sayiimagev.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            }

        }, 1500);

        mpsayi = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.bir);
        mpsayi.start();
    }
});

sayib2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener () {
    public void onClick (View sayiv2){

        mpsayi.reset();
        mpsayi.seekTo(0);

        sayilayoutt1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        sayilayoutt2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        sayibutonlar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        sayiimagev.setImageResource(R.drawable.sayi2);
        sayiimagev.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        new Handler().postDelayed( new Runnable() {

            public void run(){

                sayilayoutt1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                sayilayoutt2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                sayibutonlar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                sayiimagev.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            }

        }, 1500);

        mpsayi = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.iki);
        mpsayi.start();

    }
});
```

When I click `ImageButton`, the music is played.

[Video Demonstration](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-0K0YwZA2MF3H7d_NRgpeancBhx0lmgK/view?usp=drivesdk)

How can I solve this problem? I hope you can understand.

Comment: Hi Ahmet, welcome to StackOverflow! Please consider adding a [_Minimal, Reproducible Example_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we can troubleshoot the problem you’re facing. (Questions that don’t follow this may be closed for reasons of not providing debuggable code - see StackOverflow’s tour for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Can you share some code snippet that you have tried?

Comment: @ShahadatHossain I shared in my question.

Comment: The only question is quite impossible to solve your problem. Try to take a look @Edric's comment.

Comment: @ShahadatHossain ok. I will shared. You are right.

Comment: @ShahadatHossain . I shared

Comment: have you released your MediaPlayer object when you complete your task?

Comment: mpsayi.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mpsayi.release(); 
        }
    });

Can you try it once?  Please change the media player name for different media player object.

Comment: @ShahadatHossain I will add onCompletion them to all? Do you would change the names for all button music?

Comment: @ShahadatHossain I will add them to all? And why I need change the names?

Comment: You may take a try to add onCompletion for every MediaPlayer object that you are using in the app. I have used mpsayi.setOn..... only for dummy purpose.

After trying please let me know what happens.

Comment: You don't have to change the name same to all. Just use onCompletion for every MediaPlayer object.

Comment: @ShahadatHossain When I click two times in a button the app stop. The video : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-6pIxRneSA4Ip_PYy1GsHR_gPZgLgvXZ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @ShahadatHossain The code :

Comment: mpsayi = new MediaPlayer();
        mpsayi2 = new MediaPlayer();
        mpsayi3 = new MediaPlayer();
        mpsayi4 = new MediaPlayer();
        mpsayi5 = new MediaPlayer();
        mpsayi6 = new MediaPlayer();
        mpsayi7 = new MediaPlayer();
        mpsayi8 = new MediaPlayer();
        mpsayi9 = new MediaPlayer();

Comment: sayib1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener () {
            public void onClick (View sayiv1){

                mpsayi.reset();
                mpsayi.seekTo(0);
                mpsayi = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.bir);
                mpsayi.start();

                mpsayi.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener () {
                    public void onCompletion (MediaPlayer mp){
                        mpsayi.release();
                    }
                });
            }
        });

Comment: sayib2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener () {
            public void onClick (View sayiv2){

                mpsayi2.reset();
                mpsayi2.seekTo(0);
                mpsayi2 = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.iki);
                mpsayi2.start();

                mpsayi2.setOnCompletionListener ( new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener () {
                    public void onCompletion (MediaPlayer mp){
                        mpsayi2.release();
                    }
                });

            }
        });

Comment: can you increase the delay time 1500 to 3000 to test your app again?

Comment: If your app stoped then see the **log cat** and if possible then add the error fact in this post.

Comment: @ShahadatHossain The log : E/AndroidRuntime( 5736): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

E/AndroidRuntime( 5736): Process: com.epitcenter.hayatiogreniyorum, PID: 5736

E/AndroidRuntime( 5736): java.lang.IllegalStateException

E/AndroidRuntime( 5736):  at android.media.MediaPlayer._reset(Native Method)

E/AndroidRuntime( 5736):  at android.media.MediaPlayer.reset(MediaPlayer.java:1514)

E/AndroidRuntime( 5736):  at com.example.x_ren.hayatiogreniyorum.sayilarx$3.onClick(sayilarx.java:221)

E/AndroidRuntime( 5736):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)

etc.

Comment: @ShahadatHossain I added logs.

Comment: @ShahadatHossain I deleted reset and seekto. And problem was resolved. Thank you so much.

Comment: Thank you too dear, This is the main fact to solve any kind of problem. Be patient and solve every problem that will come in the future. :)

Comment: @ShahadatHossain Can you look at this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57020615/the-application-language-doesn-t-change-completely

Comment: Not yet. But going to take a look. :)