# The application language doesn’t change completely

Tags: android

In an application, the language doesn't change completely. I select English. It says English. But when I go to another activity. The language change to primitive language. After I go to the main activity. The language is primitive language. But when I click English or French(again) not any problem at all.

I think I didn't tell well. I hope you can understand well with video :

Reference: [Demonstration](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-5QL_5kdzg8d7QDe8UF8cwVii_-1S4JR/view?usp=sharing)

The code for changing language :

```
public void dilidegistir(String dil){
            Resources activityRes = getResources();
            Configuration activityConf = activityRes.getConfiguration();
            Locale newLocale = new Locale(dil);
            activityConf.setLocale(newLocale);
            activityRes.updateConfiguration(activityConf, activityRes.getDisplayMetrics());

            Resources applicationRes = getApplicationContext().getResources();
            Configuration applicationConf = applicationRes.getConfiguration();
            applicationConf.setLocale(newLocale);
            applicationRes.updateConfiguration(applicationConf,
                    applicationRes.getDisplayMetrics());

            finish();
            startActivity(getIntent());
    }
```

How can I solve this problem?

I need your help.

Comment: Have you seen my answer?

Answer (score 0):

According to your video demonstration, I don't think you used `sharedPreferences`.

`sharedPreferences` is mainly used for storing small amounts of data and the data is not deleted until the application uninstalls or clears the cache data from your application.

So use `sharedPreferences`. Your data will be saved all the time. If you need an example then you may take a look in this repository.

**Link:** [MultiLanguageSupport-in-Android](https://github.com/Shahadat3031/MultiLanguageSupport-in-Android)

Comment: Thanks for you answer. But When I go to another activity langıage doesn't change.

Comment: You have to put all the values in `share preferences` what you want to store permanently.

Comment: I ued this : private void setLocal(String lang) {
        Locale locale = new Locale(lang);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.locale = locale;
        getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(configuration, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

        //Temp Database
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("Settings", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        editor.putString("My_Lang", lang);
        editor.apply();
    }

    public void loadLocalLang() {

Comment: etc. I don't used showchangelanguagedialog because I change language with buttons.

Comment: Have you tried the project that I gave you in the link and is it helpful if you use it?

Comment: I tried the setLocal() and loadLocalLang() function in the project. They doesn't worked. But I think I do an trip. I try now.

Comment: First, try to clone the repo that I gave you. Try to understand what I have written in the code. Run it, Customize it. If you face any problem either tell here or please search in youtube.

Comment: Try to run properly. I have run the project first and then I have uploaded in the GitHub.